# Handling really large multi language projects

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ide, full-text-search

I am working on an really large multi language project (1000+ Classes + Configs + Scripts), with files distributed over network drives. I am having trouble fighting through the code, since the available Tools are not helping. The main problem is finding things. For the C++ Part: VS with VAX can only find files and symbols which are in the solution. A lot of them are not. Same problem with Reshaper. Right now i am stuck with doing unindexed string and file searches, which is highly inefficient on a network drive. I heared that SourceInsight would be an option since it allows you to just specify the folders that are part of the project and than indexes them, but my company wont spent money on it.

So my question ist: what Tools are there available to fight through an incredible large amount of code? And if possible they should be low cost or even free/open source.

Comment: May I ask you why don't you consider using a source code management system (Subversion, Git, TFS, etc.) at your company instead of accessing files distributed over network drives ?

Comment: Its using such a system. But the "view" is never local ;) .

Comment: VS can search through all network locatable files if you change its search options "Look in" from current document or current solution to directory set (and specify one or more network paths). Note that file searching across the network will be slower and more time consuming than having it search through files on your local HD.

Comment: @StarPilot: I know. The unindexed search on a network drive is slow. Thats exactly why i am asking the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out -

1. [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/)
2. [cscope](ftp://ftp.eeng.dcu.ie/pub/ee454/cygwin/usr/share/doc/mlcscope-14.1.8/html/index.html)
3. [idutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/idutils/)
4. [snavigator](http://sourcenav.sourceforge.net/online-docs/userguide/tutorial.html)

In every one of these tools, you would have to invest(*) some time in reading the documentation, and then building your index.  Consider switching to an editor that will work with these tools.

(*): I do mean *invest*, because it will reap dividends once you do.

hope this helps,

Comment: So far i have tried to use snavigator. It crashes after a while during the indexing process. Will try the others next.

Comment: If you like cscope and ctags, you may be interested in [CodeQuery](https://github.com/ruben2020/codequery). It makes use of the databases from cscope and ctags. Disclaimer: It's my open source project.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to maintain a large amount of code, you really should have a source code managment system, a lot of them will help you find text by indexing all the files

And Most of them will work with various language.

Otherwise you can install some indexer like Apache Lucene and index all your files...

Comment: The company is using a source code management system. But the one that is used does not provide an indexed search. The problem with apache lucine (i think u mean solr, since lucine is just the library as far as i understand it) that it is a server based solution, i am looking for something local.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at [LXR](http://lxr.sourceforge.net/en/index.shtml). This is used by many Linux kernel source listings.

Answer (score 2):

Try ndexer http://code.google.com/p/ndexer/

promises to Handle extremely large codebases!

Comment: I have tried it. And it did not work in the current version. After the configuration ok button is clicked the application just closes without starting to index.

Comment: I contacted the developer of the program, apperently his program does not work on network drives :-( .

Answer (score 2):

The Perl program [ack](http://search.cpan.org/~petdance/ack-2.00b06/) is also worth a look -- think of it as multi-file grep on steroids. The new version (in what I would call late beta) even lets you specify regexes for the files to process as well as regexes to search for -- a feature I've used extensively since it came out (I've got a subproject with 30k lines in 300+ classes, where this feature has been very helpful). You can even chain the new ack with itself so you can subselect the files to process.

Comment: Interesting idea, i will look into that. But the problem that i see with this solution is that it does not an indexed search. So it will probably work well on local hard drive but on an network drive it will still be very slow.

Answer (score 1):

> VS with VAX can only find files and symbols which are in the solution. A lot of them are not.

You can add all the files that are not in your solution and set them to not build in the settings. Your VS build will not be affected by this, but now VS knows about those files and you can search them along with your VS native files.